# Spring boot and python ends issue aio_pika

Tags: python, spring-boot, rabbitmq

hi there am using spring boot to consume messages and expecting to receive the response at the python script where I publish the message
everything works fine and when am publishing the message the spring boot is able to consume the message
but with the python code am receiving the same request as body

```py
import aio_pika
import asyncio
import json
from aio_pika import Message

from messaging import face_recognition_request_owner, face_recognition_exchange, face_recognition_request_owner_queue


async def process_message(message: aio_pika.IncomingMessage):
    async with message.process():
        print(message.info())
        print(message.body)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def got_message(message: aio_pika.IncomingMessage):
    with message.process():
        print(message.body.decode())


async def main(loop):
    connection = await aio_pika.connect_robust(
        "amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1/", loop=loop
    )

    queue_name = face_recognition_request_owner_queue
    main_exchange = face_recognition_exchange
    routing_key = face_recognition_request_owner

    # Creating channel
    channel = await connection.channel()

    # Declaring exchange
    exchange = await channel.declare_exchange(
        name=main_exchange,
        type="direct",
        auto_delete=False,
        durable=False,
    )

    # Maximum message count which will be
    # processing at the same time.
    await channel.set_qos(prefetch_count=100)

    # Declaring queue
    queue = await channel.declare_queue(queue_name, auto_delete=False)

    # Binding queue
    await queue.bind(exchange, routing_key)

    await exchange.publish(
        Message(
            bytes(json.dumps({'userId': "e4271f86-b933-465e-ae3f-f0b93335c773"}), "utf-8"),
            content_type="application/json",
        ),
        routing_key
    )
    await queue.consume(process_message)

    return connection


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    connection = loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))

    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    finally:
        loop.run_until_complete(connection.close())
```

the spring code is :

```java
  @RabbitListener(queues = BackendCodes.LOAD_OWNER_QUEUE)
    public Users loadOwner(FetchOwnerRequest fetchOwnerRequest) {
        LOGGER.info("message: {}", fetchOwnerRequest.getUserId());
        LOGGER.info("Processed and returned message");
        return usersService.loadByOwnerId(fetchOwnerRequest.getUserId());
}
```

am getting this response

```
{'body_size': 50, 'headers': {}, 'content_type': 'application/json', 'content_encoding': '', 'delivery_mode': 1, 'priority': 0, 'correlation_id': None, 'reply_to': None, 'expiration': None, 'message_id': '932b3e80e2ff6df9b5408b8f6d788f1b', 'timestamp': None, 'type': 'None', 'user_id': None, 'app_id': None, 'cluster_id': '', 'consumer_tag': 'ctag1.b7b5aa77e52adde6ee9cfeb6135e9fac', 'delivery_tag': 2, 'exchange': 'face-recognition:exchange', 'redelivered': True, 'routing_key': 'face-recognition.requestOwner'}
b'{"userId": "e4271f86-b933-465e-ae3f-f0b93335c773"}'
```

thanks for helping

Comment: any response please